# What is the inverse of SYS_EXTRACT_UTC() in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, timezone, utc, date-conversion

## The question

Let `original_date` be a `date`. How can I get back its value from the result of `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(cast(original_date as timestamp ))`, exclusively by internal Oracle functions, i.e. regardless of any timezone setting of the database.

## Background

Some stupid program writes the date values into one of the tables in UTC, that is

```
cast(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) as date)
```

is stored instead of SYSDATE in a date type column of this table.

In all other tables simply SYSDATE is stored in such columns. My task is to use these values together, so I want to do back the effect of the SYS_EXTRACT_UTC() function. I can solve this only if I specify manually my time zone, i.e by

```
cast( FROM_TZ(cast(my_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Budapest' as date)
```

But if I use `DBTIMEZONE` instead of  `'Europe/Budapest'`, then I get wrong result, probably because the summer daylight saving time is ignored by `DBTIMEZONE`

For example, when to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = '2016-05-19 13:45:12', then program stores

```
 cast(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) as date)
```

My test query is:

```
SELECT  
        original_date,
        stored_utc_date,
        cast( FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Budapest' as date) as reverted_good,
        cast( FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')  AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE as date) as reverted_wrong
from (
        select original_date, cast( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(cast(original_date as timestamp )) as date) stored_utc_date 
        from (select to_date('2016-05-19 13:45:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') original_date from dual)
    )
```

and its result is:

```
ORIGINAL_DATE       STORED_UTC_DATE     REVERTED_GOOD       REVERTED_WRONG    
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2016-05-19 13:45:12 2016-05-19 11:45:12 2016-05-19 13:45:12 2016-05-19 12:45:12
```

Comment: Have you tried `SESSIONTIMEZONE` instead of `DBTIMEZONE`?

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk - that would assume the session that runs the query is always going to be in the same time zone as the database server, or at least to declare that it is. Which probably isn't a safe assumption.

Comment: @AlexPoole if that isn't a safe assumption then I think it is impossible to reconstruct the original timestamp as a record may have originated from many different time zones (as `sys_extract_utc` uses the session time zone for the extract as well).

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk - no, the `sys_extract_utc()` call in the question is using `systimestamp`, which uses the DB server time zone (but not DBTIMEZONE). If it had used `current_timestamp` which is based on the session then you wouldn't be able to reconstruct it as that session's time zone would be unknown. (The test query is using a fixed date and implicit to-timezone conversion which muddies it slightly)

Comment: @AlexPoole Oracle docs state "If a time zone is not specified, then the datetime is associated with the session time zone." what am I missing here?

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk - a time zone *is* specified if you use `systimestamp`? (Or `current_timestamp`). Again, the test query is not specifying a time zone because of the cast to plain timestamp, but the bulk of the question is based on `systimestamp`.

Comment: @AlexPoole uhoh, thanks. Of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the systimestamp time zone region and use that:

```
FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE to_char(systimestamp, 'TZR')
```

With your test data (but changing Budapest to London as that's my local region):

```
SELECT  
        original_date,
        stored_utc_date,
        cast(FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' as date) as reverted_good,
        cast(FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE as date) as reverted_wrong,
        cast(FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'TZR') as date) as reverted_right
from (
        select original_date, cast( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(cast(original_date as timestamp )) as date) stored_utc_date 
        from (select to_date('2016-05-19 13:45:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') original_date from dual)
    )
/

ORIGINAL_DATE       STORED_UTC_DATE     REVERTED_GOOD       REVERTED_WRONG      REVERTED_RIGHT    
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2016-05-19 13:45:12 2016-05-19 12:45:12 2016-05-19 13:45:12 2016-05-19 12:45:12 2016-05-19 13:45:12
```

Except... that doesn't work all the time, because the TZR is reported as an offset (since it's based on the operating system TZ), and you can't guess a region from an offset. If the original date was in winter and you run this in summer, or vice versa, then the reverted date will be an hour out. So effectively half the reverted dates will always be wrong - but which half will depend on when you run the query.

It looks like you can get around this by using DBTIMEZONE as a local time zone:

```
cast(FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE
  as timestamp with local time zone
```

Your test query again:

```
SELECT  
        original_date,
        stored_utc_date,
        cast(FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' as date) as reverted_good,
        cast(FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE as date) as reverted_wrong,
        cast(cast(FROM_TZ(cast(stored_utc_date as TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE as timestamp with local time zone) as date) as reverted_right
from (
        select original_date, cast( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(cast(original_date as timestamp )) as date) stored_utc_date 
        from (select to_date('2016-05-19 13:45:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') original_date from dual)
    )
/

ORIGINAL_DATE       STORED_UTC_DATE     REVERTED_GOOD       REVERTED_WRONG      REVERTED_RIGHT    
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2016-05-19 13:45:12 2016-05-19 12:45:12 2016-05-19 13:45:12 2016-05-19 12:45:12 2016-05-19 13:45:12
```

A wider test query with dates across the year:

```
with t as (
  select from_tz(cast(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1-level) as timestamp), 'Europe/London')
    as original_systimestamp
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
)
select original_systimestamp,
  cast(cast(from_tz(sys_extract_utc(original_systimestamp), 'UTC')
    at time zone dbtimezone as timestamp with local time zone) as date) as good_date,
  sys_extract_utc(original_systimestamp) as utc_timestamp,
  from_tz(sys_extract_utc(original_systimestamp), 'UTC')
    at time zone to_char(systimestamp, 'TZR') as at_systimezone,
  from_tz(sys_extract_utc(original_systimestamp), 'UTC')
    at time zone dbtimezone as at_dbtimezone,
  cast(from_tz(sys_extract_utc(original_systimestamp), 'UTC')
    at time zone dbtimezone as timestamp with local time zone) as at_local_dbtimezone
from t
order by original_systimestamp;

ORIGINAL_SYSTIMESTAMP               GOOD_DATE           UTC_TIMESTAMP         AT_SYSTIMEZONE               AT_DBTIMEZONE                AT_LOCAL_DBTIMEZONE        
----------------------------------- ------------------- --------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ----------------------------
2015-06-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2015-06-01 00:00:00 2015-05-31 23:00:00.0 2015-06-01 00:00:00.0 +01:00 2015-05-31 23:00:00.0 +00:00 2015-06-01 00:00:00.0       
2015-07-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2015-07-01 00:00:00 2015-06-30 23:00:00.0 2015-07-01 00:00:00.0 +01:00 2015-06-30 23:00:00.0 +00:00 2015-07-01 00:00:00.0       
2015-08-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2015-08-01 00:00:00 2015-07-31 23:00:00.0 2015-08-01 00:00:00.0 +01:00 2015-07-31 23:00:00.0 +00:00 2015-08-01 00:00:00.0       
2015-09-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2015-09-01 00:00:00 2015-08-31 23:00:00.0 2015-09-01 00:00:00.0 +01:00 2015-08-31 23:00:00.0 +00:00 2015-09-01 00:00:00.0       
2015-10-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2015-10-01 00:00:00 2015-09-30 23:00:00.0 2015-10-01 00:00:00.0 +01:00 2015-09-30 23:00:00.0 +00:00 2015-10-01 00:00:00.0       
2015-11-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2015-11-01 00:00:00 2015-11-01 00:00:00.0 2015-11-01 01:00:00.0 +01:00 2015-11-01 00:00:00.0 +00:00 2015-11-01 00:00:00.0       
2015-12-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2015-12-01 00:00:00 2015-12-01 00:00:00.0 2015-12-01 01:00:00.0 +01:00 2015-12-01 00:00:00.0 +00:00 2015-12-01 00:00:00.0       
2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 2016-01-01 01:00:00.0 +01:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 +00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0       
2016-02-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2016-02-01 00:00:00 2016-02-01 00:00:00.0 2016-02-01 01:00:00.0 +01:00 2016-02-01 00:00:00.0 +00:00 2016-02-01 00:00:00.0       
2016-03-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2016-03-01 00:00:00 2016-03-01 00:00:00.0 2016-03-01 01:00:00.0 +01:00 2016-03-01 00:00:00.0 +00:00 2016-03-01 00:00:00.0       
2016-04-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2016-04-01 00:00:00 2016-03-31 23:00:00.0 2016-04-01 00:00:00.0 +01:00 2016-03-31 23:00:00.0 +00:00 2016-04-01 00:00:00.0       
2016-05-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/London 2016-05-01 00:00:00 2016-04-30 23:00:00.0 2016-05-01 00:00:00.0 +01:00 2016-04-30 23:00:00.0 +00:00 2016-05-01 00:00:00.0
```

But even that only works if the session time zone matches the database server's region; if I set the session time zone to something other then Europe/London it's way off. And it you're relying on being able to set the session time zone, the first query in the question with the region hard-coded isn't really much worse...

It's also worth noting that DBTIMEZONE doesn't necessarily tell you anything useful;  [Oracle recommend setting it to UTC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5004.htm#SQLRF53874). So if you can't use that, and can't really use the TZR extracted from `systimestamp` (since it's actually an offset, and you can't convert that to a region so can't know DST info), I don't think there's a way to figure out the original system time from anything held in the database. It seems that you need to supply the server time zone region at some point - either by setting the session time zone, or as in your original query.

Comment: No, this isn't right... `to_char(systimestamp, 'TZR')` is going to show the 'region' as an offset, +01:00 in my case, so the result will change depending on whether it's summertime. Hmm.

Comment: No panic, I think, that it is right. Now it shows +02:00 at me, because now it's summer. In winter it will show +01:00, and this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @mma - but that +01:00 or +02:00 is applied to every stored date, regardless of whether it was summer or winter when it was stored. So half the reverted dates will be an hour out; in summer the original winter dates will be wrong, in winter the original summer dates will be wrong.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. But, fortunately, this will cause only a temporary error at us, during the first 5 minutes after the summer/winter switch, because this conversion will be executed in every 5 minutes. Of course it would be more nice to have a perfect solution, if it is possible at all.

Comment: @mma - I'm still thinking about it. Now I think the edit I just made might be wrong too... need to test with different session TZs. In the meantime, going back to your original query, why is setting the TZR to Budapest manually wrong - does this need to run on different DBs, which are in different time zones? If the value you give matches the actual server time zone what you already had might be OK.